# Get the CSS background image path using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

can you please explain, how can i get the correct path of styles of html element that has been added through css (eg, `background:ulr()`) using javascript or jQuery.

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll('*');
img.forEach(function(i){
   var imageSrc = new Image(); 
     i.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){

      if(i.style.background){

        }
    })
});
```

can the `i.style.background` find the correct css DOM path?
i've added a fiddle.
https://codepen.io/saifudazzlings/pen/VQvooy

Comment: "can the i.style.background find the correct css DOM path" Sorry, not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) will only give you the result of the **inline styles** of an element. If you need to get the styles that have been computed from an external stylesheet, you need to use [`Window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
var bgImage = window.getComputedStyle(i).backgroundImage;
```

See the updated [codepen here](https://codepen.io/chrissantos1995/pen/eVJOEg) using `Window.getComputedStyle`. The background image URL is printed when you hover over the `div` with the background.

Comment: but, if i want to edit a css property, i should use the correct DOM path, for eg: for `<div class="a">`, in my css i've selected that with the parent element like `.parent .a{color:#000000;}`. when i am using javascript to edit that property  how can i get that correct path like $('.parent a'). @christian santos

Comment: To use JS to edit the property, you don't need to get the exact selector, you can use the DOM element directly to edit the styles (you can also pass this DOM element to jQuery by calling `$(element)` -- see this codepen for an example of modifying the bgImage on hover: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyMeZe